# Parsing multiline program output

Tags: bash, awk

I've recently been working on some lab assignments and in order to collect and analyze results well, I prepared a bash script to automate my job. It was my first attempt to create such script, thus it is not perfect and my question is strictly connected with improving it.

Exemplary output of the program is shown below, but I would like to make it more general for more purposes.

```
>>> VARIANT 1 <<<
Random number generator seed is 0xea3495cc76b34acc
Generate matrix 128 x 128 (16 KiB)
Performing 1024 random walks of 4096 steps.
> Total instructions: 170620482
> Instructions per cycle: 3.386
Time elapsed: 0.042127 seconds
Walks accrued elements worth: 534351478
```

All data I want to collect is always in different lines. My first attempt was running the same program twice (or more times depending on the amount of data) and then using grep in each run to extract the data I need by looking for the keyword. It is very inefficient, as there probably are some possibilities of parsing whole output of one run, but I could not come up with any idea. At the moment the script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
write() {
    o1=$(./progname args | grep "Time" | grep -o -E '[0-9]+.[0-9]+')
    o2=$(./progname args | grep "cycle" | grep -o -E '[0-9]+.[0-9]+')
    o3=$(./progname args | grep "Total" | grep -o -E '[0-9]+.[0-9]+')
    echo "$1    $o1   $o2     $o3"
}

for ((i = 1; i <= 10; i++)); do
    write $i >> times.dat
done
```

It is worth mentioning that `echo`ing results in one line is crucial, as I am using gnuplot later and having data in columns is perfect for that use. Sample output should be:

```
1    0.019306   3.369     170620476
2    0.019559   3.375     170620475
3    0.021971   3.334     170620478
4    0.020536   3.378     170620480
5    0.019692   3.390     170620475
6    0.020833   3.375     170620477
7    0.019951   3.450     170620477
8    0.019417   3.381     170620476
9    0.020105   3.374     170620476
10    0.020255   3.402     170620475
```

My question is: how could I improve the script to collect such data in just one program execution?

Comment: Could you please post output of  `./progname` and expected output and let us know then, we could try to do it in a single code.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 just changed the question to include the full output of `./progname`, expected output is already included in the question.

Comment: Can the output change between calls? You probably want to call the program *once*, save the results to a file, then parse the file to get your `o1`, `o2`, and `o3` values.

Comment: Values that can change are: total instructions, instructions per cycle, time elapsed and walks accured elements worth. This is why I am using `write` in the for loop, `echo` results of that function to the `times.dat` file and then program should execute again, in next loop iteration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `awk` here and could get values into an array and later access them by index `1`,`2` and `3` in case you want to do this in a single command.

```
myarr=($(your_program args | awk '/Total/{print $NF;next} /cycle/{print $NF;next}  /Time/{print $(NF-1)}'))
```

OR use following to forcefully print all elements into a single line, which will not come in new lines if someone using `"` to keep new lines safe for values.

```
myarr=($(your_program args | awk '/Total/{val=$NF;next} /cycle/{val=(val?val OFS:"")$NF;next}  /Time/{print val OFS $(NF-1)}'))
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation of `awk` program above.

```
awk '              ##Starting awk program from here.
/Total/{           ##Checking if a line has Total keyword in it then do following.
  print $NF        ##Printing last field of that line which has Total in it here.
  next             ##next keyword will skip all further statements from here.
}
/cycle/{           ##Checking if a line has cycle in it then do following.
  print $NF        ##Printing last field of that line which has cycle in it here.
  next             ##next keyword will skip all further statements from here.
}
/Time/{            ##Checking if a line has Time in it then do following.
  print $(NF-1)    ##Printing 2nd last field of that line which has Time in it here.
}'
```

To access individual items you could use like:

`echo ${myarr[0]}`, `echo ${myarr[1]}` and `echo ${myarr[2]}` for `Total`, `cycle` and `time` respectively.

Example to access all elements by loop in case you need:

```
for i in "${myarr[@]}"
do
  echo $i
done
```

Comment: How could I pass arguments to my program? Let's say I would like to use `./progname -n 10 -v 15` - how to change `Input_file` then?

Comment: @whiskeyo, if I am not wrong you are running your code with args, run it like same way you re doing(by passing argument to it) then pass its output to awk by pipe. Haven't tested it should work but. Something like `myarr=($(your_program args | awk '/Time/{print $(NF-1);next} /cycle/{print $NF;next} /Total/{print $NF}' ))` lemme know please how it goes.

Comment: Now it works as intended, thank you! Could you tell me why is it `(NF-1)` in case of `/Time/`, but just `NF` in other cases? It also saves data to array in the order of appearing in output (so total, cycle, time), is there a way of saving it in desired order?

Comment: @whiskeyo, fixed array staring from `0` to `2` in your needed order, in process of adding detailed explanation will let you know.

Comment: @whiskeyo,I have added detailed explanation now, kindly do lemme know in case of any queries here, I hope this helps you.

Comment: Everything is clear now, I understand how it works and I will be able to write similar scripts in future for my use, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @whiskeyo, glad that it helped you, cheers and happy learning.

Comment: when I run this solution all 3 values are being stored in myarr[0], with a `\n` as a field separator; `echo ${myarr[0]}` => `170620482\n3.386\n0.042127`

Comment: @markp-fuso, I have tested with OP's sample output and when I access `echo ${myarr[0]}` or `echo ${myarr[1]}` or `echo ${myarr[2]}` it gives me 3 values. If you have any suggestions those are most welcome here.

Comment: @markp-fuso, just clicked to me, may be you have used `"` quotes to have new lines saved. Which is why it given new lines as a separator is my guess, I haven't used them to make space as a array elements separator.

Comment: @markp-fuso, I have added OR solution which prints all lines by using a single `print` with spaces to make sure even someone is using `"` to keep new lines it should take array elements by space as a delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

You can execute your program once and save the output at a variable.

```
o0=$(./progname args)
```

Then you can grep that saved string any times like this.

```
o1=$(echo "$o0" | grep "Time" | grep -o -E '[0-9]+.[0-9]+')
```

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- each of the 3x search patterns (`Time`, `cycle`, `Total`) occur just once in a set of output from `./progname`
- format of `./progname` output is always the same (ie, same number of space-separated items for each line of output)

I've created my own `progname` script that just does an echo of the sample output:

```
$ cat progname
echo ">>> VARIANT 1 <<<
Random number generator seed is 0xea3495cc76b34acc
Generate matrix 128 x 128 (16 KiB)
Performing 1024 random walks of 4096 steps.
> Total instructions: 170620482
> Instructions per cycle: 3.386
Time elapsed: 0.042127 seconds
Walks accrued elements worth: 534351478"
```

One `awk` solution to parse and print the desired values:

```
$ i=1
$ ./progname | awk -v i=${i} '                     # assign awk variable "i" = ${i}
/Time/   { o1 = $3 }                               # o1 = field 3 of line that contains string "Time"
/cycle/  { o2 = $5 }                               # o2 = field 5 of line that contains string "cycle"
/Total/  { o3 = $4 }                               # o4 = field 4 of line that contains string "Total"
END { printf "%s  %s  %s  %s\n", i, o1, o2, o3 }   # print 4x variables to stdout
'
1  0.042127  3.386  170620482
```